# Joining 2 tables with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join these 2 tables based on the left table and matching the row values. The right table does not necessarily have all `ITEMNUM`s that are in the left table. And not every `VNDITNUM` is going to have an `ITEMNUM` that is in the left hand table.

```
LEFT TABLE (559 rows)
--Filtered based on column IVCOGSIX = 137
SELECT 
    ITEMNMBR
    FROM dbo.IV00101
    WHERE IVCOGSIX = 137
+---------+
| ITEMNUM |
+---------+
| Item 1  |
| Item 2  |
| Item 3  |
| Item 4  |
+---------+

RIGHT TABLE (553 rows)
--Filtered based on column VENDORID = 90505EP
SELECT 
    ITEMNMBR,
    VNDITNUM
    FROM dbo.IV00103
    WHERE VENDORID = '90505EP'
+---------+-------------+
| ITEMNUM |  VNDITNUM   |
+---------+-------------+
| Item 1  | VendorNum 1 |
| Item 2  | VendorNum 2 |
| Item 4  | VendorNum 4 |
| Item X  | VendorNum 5 |
+---------+-------------+
```

The output that I am trying to get is this -

```
JOINED TABLE (559 rows)
+---------+-------------+
| ITEMNUM |  VNDITNUM   |
+---------+-------------+
| Item 1  | VendorNum 1 |
| Item 2  | VendorNum 2 |
| Item 3  | NULL        |
| Item 4  | VendorNum 4 |
+---------+-------------+
```

However, my query keeps giving me only 548 rows, and I'm not necessarily sure what rows it is leaving out.

Here is my current query -

```
SELECT 
    cogs.ITEMNMBR,
    vin.VNDITNUM
    FROM METRO.dbo.IV00101 cogs
    LEFT JOIN METRO.dbo.IV00103 vin
        on vin.ITEMNMBR = cogs.ITEMNMBR
    WHERE
        cogs.IVCOGSIX = 137
        AND vin.VENDORID = '90505EP'
```

How can I join these 2 tables to get the 559 rows of the left table and any matching items from the right table?

Comment: Is it SQL-Server or MySQL? Database name `dbo` is usually SQL-Server, so why do you have the `mysql` tag?

Comment: @Barmar SQL-Server. Sorry, for some reason I was thinking SQL-Server's language was MySql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your join predicate vin.VENDORID = '90505EP' has effectively turned your left join into an inner join.

Try this instead.

```
SELECT 
    cogs.ITEMNMBR,
    vin.VNDITNUM
    FROM METRO.dbo.IV00101 cogs
    LEFT JOIN METRO.dbo.IV00103 vin
        on vin.ITEMNMBR = cogs.ITEMNMBR
        AND vin.VENDORID = '90505EP'
    WHERE
        cogs.IVCOGSIX = 137
```

Comment: That seemed to do it, but for some reason my output is now at 558 rows vs 559... going to do some more research as to why that is occurring. What is the reason the predication turns the left join into an inner join?

Comment: If you are looking for a value from the Right table in the Where clause. That would cause the inner join.

Comment: Ok... I think someone was making changes on the front end at the same time, which threw off some things. But now the rows are equal. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To explain what happened, essentially SQL Server will join the tables together first, and then run the where clause on the results (it's a bit more complicated then that, but this is the general way it works).  The WHERE clause as you originally ran it will remove anything that doesn't have `vin.VENDORID = '90505EP`', essentially stripping out the nulls from the result set. and returning the results of an inner join.

@SeanLange's answer works around this by shifting the filter on VENDORID into the join clause, essentially saying "filter dbo.IV00103 where VENDORID = '90505EP and then left outer join on that result"

I call (and have seen it called this before) as an Accidental Inner Join.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Definitely helpful.

Answer (score -2):

You need a Left Outer Join, so the Left table will output the full content:
`SELECT 
    cogs.ITEMNMBR,
    vin.VNDITNUM
    FROM METRO.dbo.IV00101 cogs
    LEFT OUTER JOIN METRO.dbo.IV00103 vin
        on vin.ITEMNMBR = cogs.ITEMNMBR
    WHERE
        cogs.IVCOGSIX = 137
        AND vin.VENDORID = '90505EP'`

Comment: Adding the keyword OUTER has no effect at all on the output of this query

Comment: What about
`cogs.ITEMNMBR,
    vin.VNDITNUM
    FROM METRO.dbo.IV00101 cogs
    LEFT OUTER JOIN METRO.dbo.IV00103 vin
        on vin.ITEMNMBR = cogs.ITEMNMBR
    WHERE
        cogs.IVCOGSIX = 137
        AND ( vin.VENDORID = '90505EP' OR vin.VENDORID IS NULL)`